# Good Practices for reading and handling multiple large data files?

Tags: python, json, gzip, large-data

If I have a couple large files JSON files (500MB compressed, 3GB uncompressed), what are some good practices to work with them?

I have tried:

```
combined_list = []
with gzip.open("compressed_JSON.gz", "r") as file:
    for each in file:
        combined_list.append(json.loads(each))

# do stuff with newly appended list (dataframe,
 calculations, visualization etc)
```

Which takes a fair amount of time. Plus, my memory is practically all consumed during the execution and a large amount still remains in "use" even after it finishes.

Alternatively, I have tried:

```
combined_list = []
with gzip.open("compressed_JSON.gz", "r") as file:
    for each in file:
        combined_list.append(json.loads(each))
with gzip.open("compressed_JSON2.gz", "r") as file2:
    for each in file2:
        combined_list.append(json.loads(each))

# do stuff with newly appended list (dataframe,
 calculations, visualization etc)
```

Which does two out of the five files at once. It takes maybe 7-8 times longer compared to the first method. I can't imagine how I would be able to handle all 5.

I have tried the same but without appending (so reading line by line), which is much faster, but that means I only get the object that it iterates over last.

Size of the completed appended list is only around 10MB via `sys.getsizeof()` so I'm not sure what's continuing to "eat" up my resources after the code has finished running.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be 100% what you're looking for but take it into consideration:

I had to parse and mangle an 11G File. Was plain text however.
Tried Python first but also ran into issues. What I ended up doing eventually is using C# to parse the file, mangle the data multithreaded and write into numpy-array eventually, using https://github.com/SciSharp/Numpy.NET

If you have 5 different files you could do this also multithreaded, provided you have enough RAM.

HTH.